# In Play 2.1, What to use instead of deprecated PushEnumerator

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

PushEnumerator becomes deprecated in Play framework 2.1-RC.
The documentation tells me to use Concurrent.broadcast instead. However, I the data I'm pushing is dependent on the user, so I can't broadcast the same data to each user.

In other words, Concurrent.broadcast will give me one enumerator that connects to many iteratees whereas I need many enumerators connecting to many iteratees.

Comment: I just realized I can call Concurrent.broadcast for each user, but maybe there is a more standard way of doing it?

Comment: there is Concurrent.unicast[E] but it takes a Channel parameter which I never understood why and how to pass it.

Comment: @AhmedSoliman, there's no need for passing in the Channel, it is in fact provided to you by Concurrent.unicast. See the example below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example for using Concurrent.unicast[E]:

```
// assume the following exist:
def readValueAsync(source: MySource): Future[Any]
val source: MySource = ...

// this is where the meat is:
val valueEnumerator = Concurrent.unicast[Any] {
  (channel: Concurrent.Channel[Any]) =>
    readValueAsync(source) onComplete {
      case Success(x: Any) => channel.push(x)
      case Failure(t) => channel.end(t)
    }
}

// you can then collect it using an iteratee
// since my enumerator never really ends, I only take 10 elements here
val result: List[Any] = 
  valueEnumerator through Enumeratee.take(10) run Interatee.getChunks[Any]
```